# How can I reference a document outside of the Docusaurus docs directory?

Tags: relative-path, docusaurus

I would like to organize all of my Docusaurus docs under a `docs` directory. However, I would also like to reference existing markdown documents such as `README.md` etc. How can I reference documents that are outside the `docs` directory from `sidebar.js`?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

My solution has been to include them as React Component

e.g. if you want to include the Readme from the root, place a file like this in your `docs` dir:

```
---
title: Custom README title (for sidebar etc)
hide_title: true
---

import Readme, { toc as ReadmeTOC } from '@site/../READ';

<Readme />

export const toc = ReadmeTOC;
```

Comment: I believe this is sourced from https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/3672#issuecomment-955179498